# Error in OnActivityResult after taking picture

Tags: android, firebase, null, uri

i am trying to take a picture, upload it to firebase and after that get the url of firebase and put it in a imageview.
This is the method

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {


            Uri u = data.getData();
            storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            storageReference = storage.getReference("imagenes_markers");//imagenes_chat
            final StorageReference fotoReferencia = storageReference.child(u.getLastPathSegment());

            fotoReferencia.putFile(u).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                    if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata() != null) {
                        if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference() != null) {
                            Task<Uri> result = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                            result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    String imageUrl = uri.toString();

                                    Glide.with(MapsActivity.this).load(imageUrl).into(img_marker);



                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

and this is what i use to open the camera and take the photo

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

And this is the error.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.poldevs.pabloelmapas/com.poldevs.pabloelmapas.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference

I have no idea why the Uri is null, help pls.

Comment: The data parameter in onActivityResult delivers you a bitmap of the thumbnail of the picture taken. Not an uri.

Comment: Are you sure that `u` object is not null?

Comment: the error says "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference" so I think yes